# DatePicker formatting filament v3

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-filament, filamentphp

Package Version
v3.0.0

```
DatePicker::make('reservation_date')
->label('Rezervasyon Tarihi')
->live(onBlur: true)
```

I went to DatePicker component inside and add:
`public static string $defaultDateDisplayFormat = "d/m/Y";`

However its still showing as "mm/dd/YYYY" on input before selection and after.

Is there a solution for me to show it as "dd/mm/YYYY" .

I need help <3

I expect to see 23/02/2024 however it still shows me 02/23/2024.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `format` method.

```
DatePicker::make('reservation_date')
           ->label('Rezervasyon Tarihi')
           ->live(onBlur: true)
           ->format('d/m/Y')
```

[Docs](https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/forms/fields/date-time-picker#customizing-the-storage-format)

Answer (score 0):

> hi,
> Just add displayFormat method

```
DatePicker::make('reservation_date')
           ->label('Rezervasyon Tarihi')
           ->live(onBlur: true)
           ->displayFormat('d/m/Y')
```

[filament formbuilder DatePicker doc link](https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/forms/fields/date-time-picker#customizing-the-display-format)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).